# Font Awesome Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Seen a similar question but no answer for my specific problem before someone points me in that direction.

My icons from font awesome are displaying a scroll bar on Windows Chrome but not mac. Overflow hidden won't work or a webkit css style. Tried overflow hidden on specific class and all div's related.

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


#social-media {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#social-media-icons {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.instagram-icon, .mixcloud-icon, .facebook-icon {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="second-section">
    <div id="social-media">
  <h1 class="social-media-title">Social Media</h1>
  <div id="social-media-icons">
   <div class="instagram-icon">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/area_808/" target="blank" class="instagram-link">
     <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="mixcloud-icon">
    <a href="https://www.mixcloud.com/Area808/" target="blank" class="mixcloud-link">
     <i class="fab fa-mixcloud"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="facebook-icon">
    <a href="" target="blank" class="facebook-link">
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle? Dont have much to go on from here, i notice the fab class, what does that do?

Comment: @Dorvalla I just copied that code from font awesome, I didn't add that class

Answer (score 5):

This is not a scrollbar **BUT** Because you are putting the icons inside `<a>` this little line is appearing and it's the default behavior for the `<a>` tag **( which is `a { text-decoration: underline }` )**,

So simply just add `a {text-decoration: none;}`:

```css
#social-media {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#social-media-icons {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.instagram-icon, .mixcloud-icon, .facebook-icon {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="social-media">
  <h1 class="social-media-title">Social Media</h1>
  <div id="social-media-icons">
      <div class="instagram-icon">
          <a href="#" target="blank" class="instagram-link">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mixcloud-icon">
          <a href="#" target="blank" class="mixcloud-link">
              <i class="fab fa-mixcloud"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="facebook-icon">
          <a href="#" target="blank" class="facebook-link">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hasn't removed the scroll bar, the scrollbar is viewable and actually allows you to scroll on the icons

Comment: I can't see any scroll bar, maybe that showing in your full code so there might be something else is affecting your icons

Comment: are you seeing the scrollbar here on the snippet or it's only on your website?

Comment: On the local version of my webpage it’s showing, indivisible scrollbars beside the three icons allowing me to scroll up and cut off a bit of the icon. This is why I was trying to hide overflow but had no luck

Comment: so you have to post your full html and css code or at least the section related to icons not only a small part because the issue doesn't exist here!

Comment: I've added everything I thought is needed now! I have no styling for the body tag so haven't put anything in.

Comment: Solved.. took the overflow out of * selector.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `text-decoration: none;` for all `a` tags.

This works nicely.

Comment: @JackCawthra, please post your code.We need to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `overflow-x:hidden` in the `*` style. Instead, place it in the `body`.